# How can I remove a group and its' users?

Tags: permissions

I tried to create the svn user in my server,and I create a new group `svn` and add the current user `maven` to the group `svn`.

```
sudo groupadd svn
sudo chgrp svn /usr/local/svn/repos
sudo usermod -a -G svn maven
```

Now I tried to remove subversion, and delete the groups.

Then I used:

```
sudo groupdel svn
```

When I tried to find the groups for my current user using:

```
groups
```

I got the messages:

maven@mac:/usr/local$ groups

```
maven adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers groups: cannot find name for group ID 1001
1001
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29570/how-do-i-remove-a-user-from-a-group

Comment: It does not work. I got `gpasswd: group 'svn' does not exist in /etc/group` when I use the `gpasswd -d maven svn`

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a group, all the users should be removed from the group as well when the command is called. You also have to log out and then log back in for new groups (or deleted groups) to show up when 'groups' is called.

Comment: similarly when you delete a user with  sudo deluser someuser   its own group with matching name also gets deleted